# Connect Azure Web App to vNet using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to script the setup of a bunch of resource in Azure, as part of this I need a web app to be able to communicate with a service running on a VM via the vNet.

I have created a template that seems to do everything it should to create the connection but for some reason the connection is not made. Looking in the portal shows that the site is connected to the vNet and that the certificates are in sync, but the point-to-site configuration on the vNet gateway shows no active connections.

However if I disconnect the web app from the vNet and then use the setup button in the Azure portal to reconnect to the same vNet everything works perfectly.

There must be something I'm missing in my template, but having spent the last few hours looking I cannot work out what

Here is my ARM template

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
  },
  "variables": {

  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "name": "[variables('nsgName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": []
      },
      "resources": [ ],
      "dependsOn": [ ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "name": "[variables('infrastructureNsgName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": []
      },
      "resources": [ ],
      "dependsOn": [ ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[variables('vnetName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "10.1.0.0/16"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "default",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "10.1.0.0/17",
              "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('nsgName'))]"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "infrastructure",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "10.1.254.0/24",
              "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('infrastructureNsgName'))]"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "GatewaySubnet",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "10.1.128.0/24"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "resources": [ ],
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('nsgName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('infrastructureNsgName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "kind": "api",
      "name": "[variables('gatewaySiteName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('gatewaySiteName')]",
        "hostNames": [
          "[concat(variables('gatewaySiteName'),'.azurewebsites.net')]"
        ],
        "enabledHostNames": [
          "[concat(variables('gatewaySiteName'),'.azurewebsites.net')]",
          "[concat(variables('gatewaySiteName'),'.scm.azurewebsites.net')]"
        ],
        "hostNameSslStates": [
          {
            "name": "[concat(variables('gatewaySiteName'),'.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": 0,
            "thumbprint": null,
            "ipBasedSslState": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "[concat(variables('gatewaySiteName'),'.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": 0,
            "thumbprint": null,
            "ipBasedSslState": 0
          }
        ],
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('gatewayServerFarmName'))]"
      },
      "resources": [],
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('gatewayServerFarmName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('vnetName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "sku": {
        "name": "S1",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "size": "S1",
        "family": "S",
        "capacity": 1
      },
      "kind": "",
      "name": "[variables('gatewayServerFarmName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('gatewayServerFarmName')]",
        "numberOfWorkers": 1
      },
      "resources": [ ],
      "dependsOn": [ ]
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('vnetGatewayIpName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('vnetGatewayName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('vnetGatewayIpName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('vnetName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',variables('vnetName'),'GatewaySubnet')]"
              },
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('vnetGatewayIpName'))]"
              }
            },
            "name": "vnetGatewayConfig"
          }
        ],
        "gatewayType": "Vpn",
        "vpnType": "RouteBased",
        "enableBgp": false,
        "vpnClientConfiguration": {
          "vpnClientAddressPool": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
              "172.16.201.0/24"
            ]
          },
          "vpnClientRootCertificates": [
            {
              "name": "AppServiceCertificate.cer",
              "properties": {
                "PublicCertData": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('gatewaySiteName'), '/virtualNetworkConnections/virtualNetworkConnections')).certBlob]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('gatewayVnetConnectionName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('gatewaySiteName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('vnetName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "vnetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('vnetName'))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I could never make that work just by the ARM template alone.
However if you can spend one more PowerShell command post-creation, it works beautifully:

```bsh
# Set VNET Integration for Web App

$ResourceGroup = "WeMadeThatInWestEuropeDidntWe"
$WebApp = "LearningMomentsInProduction"
$PropertiesObject = @{
       vnetName = "JimAreYouSureThisIsTheStagingVNET";
}

Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject `
                    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
                    -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config `
                    -ResourceName $WebApp/web `
                    -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force -Verbose |
                        Select -expand Properties |
                        Select VnetName

# Expected output:
#
#  VnetName                                   
#  --------                                   
#  JimAreYouSureThisIsTheStagingVNET
#
# At this point your Web App is hooked up to the VNET
```

#### EDIT:

This does not do what i thought it does.

<s>To resync Point-to-site certificates:</s>

```bsh
$ResourceGroup = "WeMadeThatInWestEuropeDidntWe"
# VNET Name or Gateway name, try with gateway name!
$vnetName = "JimAreYouSureThisIsTheStagingVNET";

$PropertiesObject = @{
  resyncRequired = "true"
}

Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
                    -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections `
                    -ResourceName $VnetName
                    -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 `
                    -Force -Verbose
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked. I can see in resources.azure.com that the vnetName on the site has been set, but there is still no connection to the vnet

Comment: Make sure your template isn't trying to set VNET integration for the Web App.

Comment: How do I then copy the certificate to the VNET gateway? As this now creates the connection but states that certificates are not in sync

Comment: You don't need to do that. The ARM stack will generate the cert automagically when you call the above PowerShell.

Comment: Yes it does create the cert on the web site side, but it doesn't get added to the vnet gateway. So when you look at the network connection on the web site it says "Certificates not in sync"

Comment: That's because you have this in the template:  `"name": "AppServiceCertificate.cer"`, remove the whole `vpnClientRootCertificates` section and redeploy. Run the PowerShell after.

Comment: I've done that and still have the same problem the `Point-to-site configuration` page on the `Virtual network gateway` shows no root certificates

Comment: Borked my edit, see my answer now. Root certificates should only show up after you run the first PowerShell in my answer.

Comment: This makes no difference, the resyncRequired property does not seem to change and it still shows no root certificates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123726/discussion-between-evilsnobu-and-mike-norgate).

Answer (score 1):

A good way of finding the correct settings after you have configured it correct in the Azure Portal, is to take a look under the hood. This can be done by taking a look through https://resources.azure.com/ or the [Resource Explorer](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/ArmExplorerBlade) in the Azure portal.

Here you will find the json in the state it is working and compare those to your ARM template. The settings can't be copied 1-on-1, but it comes close. Good luck with finding the difference.

Comment: I've already tried this and unfortunately I can't see any difference between the two

Answer (score 1):

You put it as a nested resource within the site:

(This assumes everything is under the same subscription and resource group, else, you will need to modify the parameters for `resourceId()`)

```
"properties":[],
"resources": [
                {
                    "name": "[concat(variables('webappSiteName'), '/', variables('webappSiteName'), '-vnetIntegration')]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections",
                    "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
                    "properties": {
                        "vnetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'vnetname')]"
                    },
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webappSiteName'))]"
                    ]
                }
]
```

At minimum, that what's required, however, the `Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections` resource must have the client certificate data provided (which must be configured in the P2S connection in your vnet gateway), which is the property `certBlob` which according to the documentation it is:

> A certificate file (.cer) blob containing the public key of the private key used to authenticate a Point-To-Site VPN connection.

Having that subnode worked for me, if you don't specify the certificate information, your web application(s) will show an error saying the certificates are not in sync.

Refer to the `virtualNetworkConnections` [documentation online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-02-01/sites/virtualnetworkconnections)

Hope this helps.