# Connect Azure Function App to VNet

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, azure-resource-manager

How can I deploy my function app attached to a VNet using an arm template?

Right now my arm template deploys an AppServicePlan based function app just fine and sets the "vnetName" in the "site" resource "properties" section...but after the deploy the function app still shows as "not configured" for any VNet. I can then go into the portal and add to the desired VNet in a couple of clicks...but why doesn't it work via the arm template? Can someone please provide a sample arm template to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do everything with ARM except create the VPN package - which is what makes the difference between just setting the resource properties and actually making the app connect to the VNET correctly.

Everything in this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service-web/app-service-vnet-integration-powershell) can be easily converted from PowerShell to ARM except for `Get-AzureRmVpnClientPackage`

Hypothetically, if you are using a legacy VNET, you could get the VPN client package URL via ARM because the legacy VNET resource provider supports that operation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-resource-provider-operations):

```
Microsoft.ClassicNetwork/virtualNetworks/gateways/listPackage/action
```

The ARM VNET provider does not seem to

Answer (score 1):

Upon further review this is not possible via only ARM. Here are the instructions to connect a web app to a VNet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service-web/app-service-vnet-integration-powershell

---

**Old Answer:** Here is another post trying to achieve the same with Web Apps (Functions is built on Web Apps): https://stackoverflow.com/a/39518349/5915331

---

If I had to guess based on the powershell command, try adding a sub resource to the site of type `config` with name `web`, similar to the arm template for a github deployment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-web-arm-from-github-provision.md#web-app

There may be some magic happening under the hood, however.

```
{
  "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
  "location": ...,
  "apiVersion": ...,
  "properties": ...,
  "resources": [
    "name": "web",
    "type": "config",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('siteName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "vnetName": "[parameters('vnetName')]"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: So arm is impossible?

Comment: Updating the resource via powershell seems to "work" but the app still shows as "not configured" for any VNET after doing so